# React class component is not rendering scss on website

Tags: reactjs, sass

> I was changing functional components to class components and I ran up
> to a problem. My scss was gone after updating the code. Before
> refactoring my functional component into class component everything
> was working fine in scss but then it's just like I haven't even
> imported styles.scss file in my index.js. But as you can see it is
> imported.

```
import React, {Component}from 'react';
      import './styles.scss';

        class FormInput  extends Component {
            constructor(handleChange, label, ...otherProps) {
                super(handleChange, label, ...otherProps);
            }
            render(){
            return (
                <div className="formRow">
                    {this.label && (
                        <label>
                            {this.label}
                        </label>
                    )}
        
                    <input className="formInput" onChange={this.handleChange} otherProps />
                </div>
            );
        } };
    
    export default FormInput;
```

Comment: update your `this.label` statement, the sass will apply.